# init ViewController load different XIB based on a parameter passed in

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a view controller that displays a group of thumbnails, initially it just showed 12 but I want to allow the changing of this to allow for different number, 9, 6, 4, 2.

Each of these will have a different layout so I would like to load a different XIB but use the same view controller class.  So I was hoping I can accomplish this by passing in a parameter that would let me know which XIB to load on init.

Here is my init currently:

```
-(id) initWithPriceLevel: (NSNumber *) aPriceLevel withLabelTemplate:(NSString *) aLabelTemplate withPageSize: (int) aPageSize {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.priceLevel = aPriceLevel;
        self.labelTemplate = aLabelTemplate;
        if ([aPriceLevel isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
            self.key = @"BasePrice";
        } else {
            self.key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"PriceLevel%@", aPriceLevel];
        }

        queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.thumbnailimages", NULL); 
    }
    return self;
}
```

I am assuming I could use some sort of switch on `aPageSize` that would let me load the different XIB's.

Comment: why do you not create a object with different nib everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was pretty simple, I keep the question posted in case it helps anyone else.  I modified my init like so:

```
-(id) initWithPriceLevel: (NSNumber *) aPriceLevel withLabelTemplate:(NSString *) aLabelTemplate withNibName:(NSString *) aNibName {
    if ([aNibName  isEqualToString:@""]) {
        aNibName = @"PageCollectionViewController";
    }
    self = [self initWithNibName:aNibName bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        self.priceLevel = aPriceLevel;
        self.labelTemplate = aLabelTemplate;
        if ([aPriceLevel isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
            self.key = @"BasePrice";
        } else {
            self.key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"PriceLevel%@", aPriceLevel];
        }

        queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.thumbnailimages", NULL); 
    }
    return self;
}
```

I added parameter to pass in a NIB name, if it is just an empty string I use the default NIB name.  This works great and gives me the flexibility i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create everything in the .xib with the interfaz builder, you can build part of the view using the interfaz builder, and then in the viewDidLoad you create the rest of the views dynamically depending on the number of thumbnails

Another option is to load a diffierent xib in the diferent cases:

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"my1xib" bundle:nil];
```

Or

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"my2xib" bundle:nil];
```